# So have subscription receiving callback fine, now what next?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, real-time, subscription

So I have set up the subscription, and I am receiving the callback with some data. Now what do I do next, all I am seeing is a the persons UID the time it was made and an ID which is the same as the UID.

I have been trying to find examples, and what I need to do next.

So how do I get more info about the update, someone have an example of what I need to do?

Comment: What functions do you try to realize? You can receive update when the user likes some page, and get new info (one more query to API) of all likes. Then update it in your database, for example.

Comment: Sorry but none of these are answers to my question.

Comment: If the real time updates had examples on how to achieve this I wouldn't be here asking for examples.

I have read these docs at facebook, and they are the worst documentation for getting examples and know hows that I have ver come across.

Now I am well aware of what the subscription callback contains, and I am hoping that instead of telling me what it is for and how it works. Someone has an actual example to two to get me on my way.

Answer (score 1):

the callback tells you something happened.
And to get "what is the details for that change", you need to get it based on the info in the callback (e.g. by reading the user feed / user profile for that UID).

you can find example in FB doc on the real time update.